# Make virtual scroller scroll to the top with a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my vuetify app I am using the vuetify [virtual scroller](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/virtual-scroller/) for requesting more content as the user scroll down the list. Now, when the user makes a new request I would like to load the new list and make the virtual scroller scroll back to the top.

Currently, the new list is loaded in the virtual scroller but I cannot find a way to scroll back to the top, the scroller stays in the middle of the list. I want my method, which is called whenever a new query is made, to also make the virtual scroller scroll to the top.

What I've tried so far:

1. Setting the parameters of the virtual scroller, first and last to 0 and 11 (size of what is to be displayed)
2. Reloading the component with a v-if to reset it.
3. Looked into the vuetify documentation, nothing seems to be related to my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add a snip of your code?

Comment: did you find a solution?